# RxJS Scan in Typescript with different types for accumulator and updated value

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Trying to use RxJS with different types for "input and output" :

```
a$: Subject<Request>;
b$: Observable<Pair[]>;
```

Where I pass the request, it gets processed in the `scan` function, and added to accumulator:

```
this.b$ = this.a$.pipe(
  startWith([]),
  scan(this.accumulator),
  shareReplay(),
);

accumulator(acc: Pair[], modification: Request): Pair[] {
  // .... process request and add the pair derived from request to acc
  return acc
}
```

But typescript immediately starts whining about the accumulator not being applicable to the defined types, and it only works with setting `modification: any`, which is like not writing typescript at all.

Am I misunderstanding something about Rx? This pattern has worked previously for me, when I get to runtime.

Comment: You can force types with `scan<T, R>(...)`

Comment: it might be complaining about `startWith( [] )`. With that you'll have both `[]` and `Request` on the stream, that you'll process with `scan`. To tell scan to start with `[]` in the accumulator use `scan(this.accumulator, [])`

Answer (score 1):

don't know if you found your answer but all you have to do is split subject, and observer definitions:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-scan